# OpenCV python findContours wrong results

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

i'm trying to find coordinates of white regions in my image using python and OpenCV.
this should be a simple task using erode => threshold => findContours.

this is my code:

```
th_er = cv2.erode(th, np.ones((15, 15), np.uint8))
th_er = cv2.bitwise_not(th_er)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(th_er, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cntr in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    cv2.rectangle(th_er, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (100, 100, 100), 5)

cv2.imshow('il', th_er)
cv2.waitKey()
```

my problem is that "findContours" is returning weird results like shown in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krvin.png).

so, anyone encountered this behavior or knows any possible fix ?

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0XZK.png) is the original image.

Comment: what is your original image?

Comment: findcontours is working on the image i posted "th_er" but without the gray boxes ofc. the original image is in the same shape but contains some text wich was eroded to get the zones

Comment: Did you convert the image into grayscale image?

Comment: yes it is a thresholded image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img = cv2.imread('try.jpg', 0) # (200, 1427)
img2 = cv2.imread('try.jpg', -1) # (200, 1427, 4)

# gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # <-- you can use this to convert into grayscale image and then feed it to cv2.erode(img2, .....)
th_er = cv2.erode(img, np.ones((15, 15), np.uint8))
th_er = cv2.bitwise_not(th_er)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(th_er, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cntr in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    cv2.rectangle(img2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (200, 100, 100), 5)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,20))

plt.imshow(img2)
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

**EDIT:**

It works fine now.

`th_er1 = 255-cv2.bitwise_not(th_er)` As I said object should be in white and background should be in black. You had vice versa of it. By subtracting 255, It will be now in correct format.

```
# img = cv2.imread('try.png', 0) # (200, 1427)
img = cv2.imread('try.png') # (200, 1427, 4)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # <-- you can use this to convert into grayscale image and then feed it to cv2.erode(img2, .....)
_, th = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+ cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 
th_er = cv2.erode(th, np.ones((15, 15), np.uint8))
th_er1 = 255-cv2.bitwise_not(th_er) # <----- here

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(th_er1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cntr in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (200, 100, 100), 5)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,20))

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Comment: so you didn't change "findContours" or the drawing of  boxes. what is my problem then ?

Comment: I converted them to grayscale. actually you didn't specify what is your th. 
steps should be `gray image -> binarize it (white for object, black for background) -> create contours` If you can give a original image it will be very helpful. Can you check all the steps again. Whether it has been binarized correctly or not

Comment: it was grayscaled then thresholded before this code.

Comment: Also `th_er = cv2.bitwise_not(th_er)` use some other variable because if you will re run the code it will inverse the binary colours.

Comment: _, th = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+ cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

Comment: solved, thanks.
i think that the image maintains some information of it's previous states in the run time. used a different var name and it's solved